# Setting the opacity of a HTML input field's text

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to set the opacity for the **text** of an input field `<input type='text' name='name' />`?

Adding a CSS style like below just sets the opacity for the **whole** input field.

`input {
    opacity: 0.5
}`

Comment: Use RGBA colors. This should help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not set the `opacity` in the way you have tried. You could however use an rgba color which would allow you to set the alpha channel:

```css
input {
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<input value="Lorem ipsum sit amet">
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `rgba(r,g,b,a)` function to set color style of the text

for example to get opaque red text use this style

```
input {
  color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}
```

more info can be found here https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_rgba.asp